# Python Promise: how to wait for page load or webelement using promises?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, promise

**I'm trying to move away from Expected Conditions and explicit waits** using the Promise package for Python.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from promise import Promise

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1500, 1000)
driver.maximize_window()

about = '#fsl > a:nth-child(3)'
products = 'body > header > div > nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a'

print ">> START <<"

promise = Promise(driver.get('https://google.co.uk'))
promise.then(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(about).click())

assert driver.find_element_by_css_selector(products).is_displayed() == True

driver.quit()
```

This goes to the google webpage, clicks the "About" link at the bottom and asserts the link "Our products" is visible on the next page.

This test fails because the assertion is executed right away after the `click()` command promise. This makes sense, the promise delivers, but the page still takes some time to load.

How to create a promise that will simulate waiting for a webelement to be visible or the page to fully load?

---

UPDATE:

I've been trying the `_wait` method that Promises have, but to no avail:

```
promise.then(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(about).click())\
._wait(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(products).is_displayed())

assert driver.find_element_by_css_selector(products).is_displayed() == True
```

---